# Extracting images from an APK

Tags: apk

I've tried to extract the images of 2 different APKs, from the drawable folder.

One of them contains PGT files, and the other one contains mostly TEX files and one ACT file.

Couldn't open neither.

Is there any other way to extract an APK's images other than just opening it using WinRAR?

Or maybe there's a way to open those PGT and TEX files? (Couldn't find any.)

Comment: Android uses Draw9patch for some images: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: @ce4 Is it possible to convert those to viewable format?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry